# I can't find my skewer that came with the trainer. Can I use my bike skewer?

Tags: trainer, skewer

I have misplaced my trainer bike skewer. Can I use the one from my bike?  I am not concerned about scratches.

Comment: With the trainer I recently bought it would probably work to use the bike's skewer, but the skewer would be likely to get damaged over time.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't. You'll damage the skewer you have, which will make it unreliable on the road, if not unusable.

Basic skewers with plastic on the nut will certainly be damaged, the plastic gets crushed and then you can't use it. Even skewers with more expensive metal parts will be subject to forces they weren't designed for. If a nice skewer should be damaged in this way, that is more expensive than the right trainer specific part, it is a false economy.

I should have your LBS order in something suitable

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the trainer.

If the trainer had a special skewers that had ends shaped specifically to fit in the trainer, you can't use a standard skewer. The trainer will not hold the bike properly. The bike coming out of the trainer with you on it would be bad.

If the trainer accepts normal skewers, but supplied a spare so your regular one does not get mashed up, then it's fine. I'd buy a cheap spare and mess that up though.